# jsPDF render div header and auto table from HTML

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jspdf

I am using jsPDF to convert HTML to Pdf. Normally when i want only table to pdf is working fine. Here the working code is,

```
var doc = new jsPDF('l');
var elem = document.getElementById("basic-table");
var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(elem);
doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, { startY: 20 });
document.getElementById("output").src = doc.output('datauristring');
```

But Now need to append header details in the pdf. I try many code to render div element and table in the same pdf. Here the tried code is ,

```
var doc = new jsPDF('l');
doc.fromHTML($('#printHeader').get(0), 15, 15, {
                'width': 170,
                'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
            }); 
var elem = document.getElementById("basic-table");
var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(elem);
doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, { startY: 20 });
document.getElementById("output").src = doc.output('datauristring');
```

Cannot Working !.